# How to resize images to display from database

Tags: c#

I am doing a small project where I have to display all images from database to Listview.
I am passing image id,width,and height as querystring parameter.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Handler/ImageHandler.ashx?ImgHeight=150&ImgWidth=200&ImgID="+Eval("Image_ID")%>' Height="150px" Width="200px"/>
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {

    string imgwidth = context.Request.QueryString["ImgWidth"];
    string imgheight = context.Request.QueryString["ImgHeight"];
    string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImgID"];
    if (imgwidth != string.Empty && imgheight != string.Empty && (imgwidth != null && imgheight != null))
    {
        if (!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(imgwidth).IsEmpty && !System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(imgheight).IsEmpty)
        {
            //create unit object for height and width. This is to convert parameter passed in differen unit like pixel, inch into generic unit.
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit widthUnit=System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(imgwidth);
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit heightUnit = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(imgheight);
            //AFTER THIS ???
        }

    }
}
```

when I display image directly from database some images get stretch and doesn't look good, this is because the image size is large. So I need to display the images just for thumbsnail in image gallery.

Comment: Do you preserve the ratio?

Comment: Using css to add the correct size to the images isn't an option?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GetThumbnailImage` Method

refer the code

```
public Void GenerateImage(int iWidth,int iHeight,byte[] ImageBytes)
{
System.Drawing.Image image = byteArrayToImage(ImageBytes)

 // create the actual thumbnail image
        System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(iWidth, iHeight, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);

        // make a memory stream to work with the image bytes
        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();

        // put the image into the memory stream
        thumbnailImage.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.Imageformat.Jpeg);

        // make byte array the same size as the image
        byte[] imageContent = new Byte[imageStream.Length];

        // rewind the memory stream
        imageStream.Position = 0;

        // load the byte array with the image
        imageStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);

        // return byte array to caller with image type
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
    }

    public bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return true;
    }
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to give the image a new size, while preserving the aspect ratio:

```
public static Image ResizeCanvas(Image original, Size newSize, Color background)
    {
        int xStart = (newSize.Width / 2) - (original.Width / 2);
        int yStart = (newSize.Height / 2) - (original.Height / 2);

        // Create blank canvas
        Bitmap resizedImg = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImg);

        // Fill canvas
        gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(background), new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize));

        gfx.DrawImage(original, xStart, yStart, original.Width, original.Height);

        return resizedImg;
    }
```